# Wrong alignment of textView. I want to make there alignment of all right textView on the redline

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have created this as custom dialog. I am using two text views left one and the right one. I am using recycler to display this Dialog.

I want all right textViews should be aligned on the red line.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/regular_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/regular_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/regular_padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iet_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:text="Email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iet_desc_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/half_padding"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:text="Email" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Custom Dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach will be to use weight i think. One working code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Email:" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="safallwa.aas@gmail.com" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Subject:" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="very interesting subject" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Body:" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." />
</LinearLayout>
```

The output is

[image: output is as u wanted]

Comment: Its not working for me though. please check this link. https://postimg.org/image/46jqklty7/

Comment: perhaps you are using some extra padding on those textviews. this is very much proven method & code. first simply copy paste my code and see the output then you may get an idea whats possibly going wrong

Comment: Thanks, I forget to remove wrap_content. it wroks great.

Answer (score 0):

If your titles are static, you can just set a static width for the "iet_title" `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/iet_title"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:text="Email" />
```

Comment: titles are not static, it can be email, subject, body, phone, address, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iet_title1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Email" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iet_desc_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Subject" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iet_desc_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Body" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iet_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Dymmy@gmail.com" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iet_desc_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Dummy task" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iet_desc_body1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="down vote favorite I have created this as custom dialog. I am using two text views left one and the right one. I am using recycler to display this Dialog.Email kbjhklilkilili" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use TableLayout with 2 columns and 3 rows. It looks nice and all your elements will be arranged properly.

Refer this doc: [Android TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add weightsum=1 to your parent layout. 
All Child layout width match parent and layout weight = 0.5.  You can change the layout weight as per your needs.